# Create metafields for smart collection on shopify

Tags: api, python-requests, shopify

**Set-up**

I have created a smart collection in Shopify.

In the admin of the shop I can set the SEO metafields of the collection, however I'd like to do this via the API.

---

**Code**

To do so, I use the following code,

```
payload = {
    'metafields': [
        {
           'namespace': 'global',
           'key': 'title_tag',
           'value': collection_title + ' – Kappersstoelshop.nl',
           'value_type': 'string',
           },
        {
           'namespace': 'global',
           'key': 'description_tag',
           'value': collection_title +' ✅ Gratis bezorgd vanaf €70 ✅  14 dagen bedenktijd ✅  Leasen, gespreid of achteraf betalen',
           'value_type': 'string',},
        ]
    }

r = requests.post(shop_url + '/collections/'+collection_id+'/metafields.json',
                  json=payload,headers=headers)
```

where `collection_title` and `collection_id` are strings.

I have based this code on the method to insert metafields to products, namely,

```
r = requests.post(shop_url + '/products/'+product_id+'/metafields.json',
                  json=payload,headers=headers)
```

---

**Issue**

The above code yields a `<Response [400]>` error code, which according to [Shopify API response codes](https://shopify.dev/concepts/about-apis/response-codes) means;

*The request was not understood by the server, generally due to bad syntax or because the Content-Type header was not correctly set to application/json.
This status is also returned when the request provides an invalid code parameter during the OAuth token exchange process.*

Now, admittedly Shopify doesn't give any explanation on how to exactly create a metafield of a collection, other than naming collections [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/metafield) as a resource that can have metafields and stating something [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/metafield#create-2021-04) about creating metafields for 'shop resources'.

---

**Question**

Any idea how to create a metafield for a (smart) collection via the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with your given payload, the API responds with 404 and the following error for me:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "metafield": "Required parameter missing or invalid"
    }
}
```

The metafields endpoint doesn't allow to create multiple metafields in a single request. It takes only a single metafield in the body https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/metafield?api%5Bversion%5D=2021-04#create-2021-04 .
You'll probably need to perform multiple POST requests with a payload like the following:

```
payload = {
    'metafield':
        {
           'namespace': 'global',
           'key': 'title_tag',
           'value': collection_title + ' – Kappersstoelshop.nl',
           'value_type': 'string',
         }
    }
```

Another option, if you really need the insertion of the metafields to be atomic, would be to change the value_type to json_string and combine all data in the value.